# Simplifying a robocopy batch to try multiple drive letters

Tags: batch-file

I've created a batch file to run an ondemand robocopy from one drive to another. The problem is the external drives do not always have the same letter.

Here is the code. The file works, and provides me the behavior I expected. I am wondering if there is a way to simplify this.

```
:: This is my robocopy script
IF EXIST "E:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy1 else goto nextdrive1 

:robocopy1
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "E:\Appraisal Service" /E

:nextdrive1
IF EXIST "F:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy2 else goto nextdrive2

:robocopy2
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "F:\Appraisal Service" /E

:nextdrive2
IF EXIST "G:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy3 else goto nextdrive3

:robocopy3
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "G:\Appraisal Service" /E

:nextdrive3
IF EXIST "H:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy4 else goto nextdrive4

:robocopy4
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "H:\Appraisal Service" /E

:nextdrive4
IF EXIST "I:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy5 else goto nextdrive5

:robocopy5
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "I:\Appraisal Service" /E

:nextdrive5
IF EXIST "J:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy6 else goto nextdrive6

:robocopy6
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "J:\Appraisal Service" /E

:nextdrive6
IF EXIST "K:\Appraisal Service" goto robocopy7 else goto quit

:robocopy7
robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "K:\Appraisal Service" /E

:quit
exit
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot believe the script works, the command after `else` will never be executed... Anyway, you are looking for the [`for` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%a in (E F G H I J K) do IF EXIST "%%a:\Appraisal Service" robocopy "Z:\Appraisal Service" "%%a:\Appraisal Service" /E
```

`%%a` is set to each target drive letter in turn, if the directory exists on the target drive letter, do the copy.

Comment: Magoo, your code doesn't work. Robocopy doesn't like the %%a 



C:\Users\Jesse\Desktop\Cloud Backup\%A:\Appraisal Service\

is the result trying to use the %%a 

any thoughts?

Comment: The revised version you posted (you should not replace the original question - just edit-in your new code, marked in as an edit) appears to bear no relation to your comment. It would appear that you are attempting to run this code from the prompt, but it is a batch line, so the `%%` use for the metavariable `a` needs to be reduced to `%` to run from the prompt. Note that `A` and `a` are different metavariables. No idea where `c:\users...` comes from - it's not in the code. To highlight text enclose in backticks or asterisks or double-asterisks (shaded,italic,bold)

Answer (score 0):

This is the final code. Thanks to Magoo (who was correct). I figured out my mishap (I missed a ":" that caused it to not work).

```
color 17
cls
@echo off 
echo.
echo Cloud Backup to External Hard Drive Backup Utility  
echo.  
echo Please ensure External Hard Drive is plugged into the computer
echo and that it is showing in "This PC"  
pause

SET SOURCE=Z:

FOR %%a in (E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R) DO IF EXIST "%%a:" robocopy %SOURCE% "%%a\Appraisal Service Backup" /E

pause
```